# Is mass spectrometry convenient to separate elements in a mixture?

Tags: particle-physics, magnetic-fields, nuclear-physics, accelerator-physics, mass-spectrometry

Are particle accelerators coupled to spectrometers ever used to separate and extract different components of a mixture? If so, how much substance can be treated per day in this way? Would it be a viable way to treat tech waste?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calutron

Comment: If you look at the process, you can easily find out, that it can not be used for tech waste.

Comment: @trula - ok, as an accelerator person, why does mass separation not work for tech waste? It isn’t easy to see for me.

Comment: It takes too much energy, to accelerate small amount of matter, in tech waste you have large amounts of matter, most of it you could separate ba cheaper means.

Comment: @trula - that is true for all kinds of waste, not just tech waste. Still it was clearly useful in the past.